# Excel: Cross-workbook data mining

Tags: excel

At work, we track our payments collected in an effort to reach a daily goal. As such, our payments are tracked in our individual Excel workbooks. An example of said workbook is below:

[Google Docs Payment Log (modified)](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1aiyslTPkHXCxv8nIhrrKQmM29d-cSaJjwCG3di62Vjo/edit?usp=sharing)

We use Excel 2013 at work. I have a "Tracker Log" that is a separate workbook. Originally I had it tracking inside the existing workbook, but moved it to the outside workbook for ease of copy/paste for our team lead.

In the Tracker Log, I have the current workable days in Column A (dates occurring Monday through Friday for the month of August). Each day is supposed to list how many payments were collected and the sum of the payments. That part, I figured out from research and had the following formula with the Payment Log:

```
=IF(NOT(ISBLANK(A2)), COUNT(B2:INDEX(B2:$B$500,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(B2:$B$500="",0),0))),"")
```

and a similar one for SUM. It worked great for its purpose, and I was pleased when it was in the Payment Log. Moving it to the Tracker Log, however, did not produce intended results. The formula works; it's not broken. The undesired result, however, is that instead of each line producing the day's information, the formula causes it to skip down to the corresponding row in the Payment Log. That is, instead of Row 2 being 8/1 and Row 3 being 8/2's information, Row 1 is 8/1 and the row that 8/2 falls on in the Payment Log is the row the Tracker log populates. (View Sheet2 to see the undesired behavior.)

What formula do I need to use for the desired behavior?

**EDIT**

After sneakily taking home the information (and modifying so no account information is released), I've found the selected answer does not work at all. See the (modified) Google Spreadsheet above to show what is happening.

Comment: I addited my answer. It should work as you want it. (If not, simply tell) ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me to make it work, I need in B2:

```
=IFERROR(COUNTIF(INDEX(Sheet1!B:B,MATCH(A2,Sheet1!A:A,0)):INDEX(Sheet1!B:B,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(Sheet1!B:B,MATCH(A2,Sheet1!A:A,0)):INDEX(Sheet1!B:B,MATCH(A2,Sheet1!A:A,0)+100)=0,0)),"<>"),"")
```

and in C2:

```
=IFERROR(SUM(INDEX(Sheet1!C:C,MATCH(A2,Sheet1!A:A,0)):INDEX(Sheet1!C:C,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(Sheet1!B:B,MATCH(A2,Sheet1!A:A,0)):INDEX(Sheet1!B:B,MATCH(A2,Sheet1!A:A,0)+100)=0,0))),"")
```

And then copy down B2:C2.

> This are array formulas and must be confirmed with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>.

**EDIT** there was just a small error in it :P

For B2:

```
=IFERROR(COUNTIF(INDEX('Sept 2016'!B:B,MATCH(A2,'Sept 2016'!A:A,0)):INDEX('Sept 2016'!B:B,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX('Sept 2016'!B:B,MATCH(A2,'Sept 2016'!A:A,0)):INDEX('Sept 2016'!B:B,MATCH(A2,'Sept 2016'!A:A,0)+100)=0,0)+MATCH(A2,'Sept 2016'!A:A,0)-2),"<>"),"")
```

and for C2:

```
=IFERROR(SUM(INDEX('Sept 2016'!C:C,MATCH(A2,'Sept 2016'!A:A,0)):INDEX('Sept 2016'!C:C,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX('Sept 2016'!B:B,MATCH(A2,'Sept 2016'!A:A,0)):INDEX('Sept 2016'!B:B,MATCH(A2,'Sept 2016'!A:A,0)+100)=0,0)+MATCH(A2,'Sept 2016'!A:A,0)-2)),"")
```

> This are array formulas and must be confirmed with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>.

I missed the part to offset outcome of `MATCH(TRUE,...,0)` so the upper index will not count from row 1. Sorry for this.

The formulas from B2 and C2 can be copied down. Also used your sheet naming. ;)

**EDIT 2**

Theoretical `COUNTIF` cannot return `TRUE`. I suggest some different error which simply will not pop up on my excel (also google sheets). Please try this formula for B2:

```
=IFERROR(SUM((INDEX('Sept 2016'!B:B,MATCH(A2,'Sept 2016'!A:A,0)):INDEX('Sept 2016'!B:B,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX('Sept 2016'!B:B,MATCH(A2,'Sept 2016'!A:A,0)):INDEX('Sept 2016'!B:B,MATCH(A2,'Sept 2016'!A:A,0)+100)=0,0)+MATCH(A2,'Sept 2016'!A:A,0)-2)<>"")*1),"")
```

> This is an array formula and must be confirmed with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>.

Comment: Attempted to use this and got an error on incorrect number of arguments, but can't tell what for.

Comment: Actually, managed to copy/paste, and it doesn't fully work as intended. I'll post an update tonight when I'm home.

Comment: Odd, when I tried it at work, it didn't work entirely properly. It would do 8/1 properly, but 8/2 was not correct, and 8/3 was far from correct. I'll have to check it out tomorrow at work again. Marking as answer for now, thanks!

Comment: Okay, for whatever reason it's not working at work. For example, instead of 8, 6, 8, 12 for counts for days 1 thru 4 I'm getting 8, 2, 14, 26. Any idea?

Comment: Are the dates real dates? Or are some lines missing where they should not? I've tested it withe the data you provided, and after making the dates real datevalues, it worked without errors... I'm confused...

Comment: Same here. They are date values. It's listed as Short Date in the type. It should match on both. I wish I had access to it from home so I could tweak it more, though.

Comment: if you're still around, I updated the information and can reproduce them not working properly. Hopefully you can still help.

Comment: So much closer. There must be an error in the COUNTIF; it only returns "TRUE" instead of a numerical value. The SUM works, however. And thank you!

Comment: works as intended. The only behavior i could notice is, that in Google Sheets `COUNTIF` seems to not throw errors. This way it shows `1` while it should be `""`.

Comment: How about in Excel 2013? Tried it in 2016, and did not count, only showed "TRUE" for the entire column.

Comment: I've added a different formula. Still I cannot reproduce the problem with `TRUE` :(

Comment: The sample google sheet has wrong results, because the formula there is different than this answer (last MATCH is not included).

Comment: Oddly enough, it worked at work. I'll give the bounty when I get home; can't figure out how to do it mobile. Thanks for all your help!